# Android Realm Performance

Tags: android, realm

I have a trouble with Realm in my Android app. What I am trying to do is to use rxJava and I have a service which gives me access to Realm's instance, like for example here https://realm.io/news/using-realm-with-rxjava/.

```
public Observable<List<InboxRealmEntity>> getDatabaseChangeObserver(final String accountId) {
    return RealmDatabaseProvider
        .getInstance(configuration,
            realm -> realm
                .where(InboxRealmEntity.class)
                .contains(InboxRealmEntity.ACCOUNT_ID, accountId)
                .findAll()
                .asObservable()
                .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
                .map(inboxRealmEntities -> inboxRealmEntities.sort(InboxRealmEntity.CREATED_AT, Sort.DESCENDING)))
                .switchMap(realmResultsObservable -> realmResultsObservable);
}
```

but when I open my View and expect instant response from Realm where there are about 100 records. It takes about 3 or 4 seconds instead of. What I did wrong?

Comment: What is `RealmDatabaseProvider`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
public Observable<List<InboxRealmEntity>> getDatabaseChangeObserver(final String accountId) {
    return RealmDatabaseProvider.getInstance(configuration,
            realm -> realm
                .where(InboxRealmEntity.class)
                .contains(InboxRealmEntity.ACCOUNT_ID, accountId)
                .findAllSorted(InboxRealmEntity.CREATED_AT, Sort.DESCENDING)
                .asObservable();
}
```

On `InboxRealmEntity`, add `@Index` on your `createdAt` field.

Comment: Thank you! Seems it's works! Can you please explain why?

Comment: I'm actually not sure, I just figured you have some sort of unnecessary mapping going on, and it was indeed the case.